# Mat-tabs on mat-dialog not working when selectedIndex change asynchronously

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I have a problem when render mat-tabs on mat-dialog. I used selectedIndex to select the index of the tabs dynamically and I want to change it asynchronously e.g server-side call or setTimeout. But it doesn't work. The tabs body shows no content for that index. I reproduce it in stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tabs-on-mat-dialog-problem

N.B: I know it can be solved using setTimeout with 500ms. But it isn't the expected solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure the display of the content by adding an `*ngIf` directive. This ensures the display of content but it makes you lose the animation at the beginning:

```
<mat-tab-group *ngIf="selectedIndex!=undefined" [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: it almost solve my problem. But the problem is that if I initialize the index and change it after setTimeout, it goes into blank state. Can you please tell me why this happens?

Comment: If you initialize the `selectedIndex`, it will not be `undefined` and the condition in the `*ngIf` directive will always be `true`. Why do you wanbt to initialize it exactly ? Maybe it is important for you to show the first tab and then the animation to the second ?

Comment: You can use a `loaded: boolean = false;` variable in your component that you set to `true` after your asynchronous call and use in the `*ngIf` ?

Comment: Actually I want to know why the tabs behaves weirdly? I know the solution actually. I already mentioned one solution in the question. But I want to know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the problem by passing the `selectedIndex` from the `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DialogComponent } from './dialog/dialog.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  public index = { selectedIndex: 0 }

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.index.selectedIndex = 1, 100)
  }

  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, { data: this.index });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
  }
}
```

In the `DialogComponent` you could get the data by injecting MAT_DIALOG_DATA

```
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data) { }
```

Finally, here is the code example for the `dialog.component.html`

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="data.selectedIndex">
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: But I don't want to pass the index from parent component. I have a situation where the index will be changed based on the http call and it is from dialog component.